# Custom proof environment preserving optional argument

Tags: environments, optional-arguments

I basically want to obtain the result (replace Proof -> Solution, and `mdframed` around the environemnt) simply by the code:

```
\begin{solution}
    Set Theory Best Theory.
    \begin{align*}
        2 = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}
    \end{align*}
\end{solution}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

This can be easily done using `\renewenvironment`. My main issue lies in preserving the optional argument in the proof environment, i.e. something like this would still work:

```
\begin{solution}[Proof]
    Set Theory Best Theory.
    \begin{align*}
        2 = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}
    \end{align*}
\end{solution}
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I do not have a working `solution` environment working. The first image above can be made possible by:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\begin{mdframed}\begin{proof}[Solution]}
  {\end{proof}\end{mdframed}}
```

But it will not accept any arguments (so the second image will not be obtained)

Comment: Can you please add the definition you have of `solution`?

Comment: @egreg please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is easy:

```
\newenvironment{solution}[1][Solution]
  {\begin{mdframed}\begin{proof}[#1]}
  {\end{proof}\end{mdframed}}
```

If you call `\begin{solution}`, you'll get “Solution” as the label; with `\begin{Solution}[Hint]` you'll get “Hint” as the label.